# RegEx Find Text Between Dashes

Tags: c#, regex

I have the below input:

```
(FPL-XXXXX-IG
-GLF5/M-SDE2E3FGHIRWXY/E
-ABCD0300
-N0292F060 UPTON1C UPTON/N0447F430 UL975 BARTN UP17 NOKIN UN862
RILES UL180 MERLY DCT GAPLI/M080F430 DCT 46N015W 45N020W/M080F470
37N030W 33N040W 26N050W 18N058W/N0448F470 DCT BNE DCT
-EFGH0933 IJKL
-PBN/A1B1C1D1 DOF/141218 REG/XXXXX
EET/EISN0114 EGGX0132 LPPO0239 KZWY0526 TTZP0830
46N015W0208 45N020W0239 37N030W0410 33N040W0526
SEL/TEST ORGN/KHOUUVAX PER/C
E/1128 P/TBN R/UVE D/2 10 YELLOW A/RED WHITE BLUE C/TBN)
```

I'd like to get the text between the third line starting with the dash (`N0292F060`) up until the beginning of the next line starting with the dash (`-EFGH0933`).

Ideal output would be `"N0292F060 UPTON1C UPTON/N0447F430 UL975 BARTN UP17 NOKIN UN862 RILES UL180 MERLY DCT GAPLI/M080F430 DCT 46N015W 45N020W/M080F470 37N030W 33N040W 26N050W 18N058W/N0448F470 DCT BNE DCT".`

How to get it correct?

Comment: why are you banging your head for hours..? have you thought about using `string.Split()` method ...?

Comment: Copy paste my second example with the quoted string values into a console app and test it there.. you will see when you hover over spltArray, that it will give you what you are looking for to get you started.. read up on string.Split method when you have some spare time as well

Comment: Yea I I've gone with the Split version.  I was being requested to right this with Regex, though.  Not a personal choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.split() function which takes a character array which you want to use as split flag.
In your question you want to split the string based upon - character, see following code if this makes sense and works..

```
   char[] delimiter = {'-'};
   String[] arr = data.Split(delimiter,StringSplitOptions.None);
   Console.WriteLine(arr[6]);
   //this will return the following string
   /*
   N0292F060 UPTON1C UPTON/N0447F430 UL975 BARTN UP17 NOKIN UN862
   RILES UL180 MERLY DCT GAPLI/M080F430 DCT 46N015W 45N020W/M080F470
   37N030W 33N040W 26N050W 18N058W/N0448F470 DCT BNE DCT*/
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone with the Split version.  I was being requested to right this with Regex, though.  Not a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

here is something that you can do to get you started..

```
   var spltLargString = yourString.Replace("(", "");
   var spltArray = spltLargString.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`From here you need to write your own parsing code or conditional checks to evaluate the data if necessary..

`Below is a string representation of the above`

```
var spltLargString = "(FPL-XXXXX-IG-GLF5/M-SDE2E3FGHIRWXY/E-ABCD0300-N0292F060 UPTON1C UPTON/N0447F430 UL975 BARTN UP17 NOKIN UN862RILES UL180 MERLY DCT GAPLI/M080F430 DCT 46N015W 45N020W/M080F47037N030W 33N040W 26N050W 18N058W/N0448F470 DCT BNE DCT-EFGH0933 IJKL-PBN/A1B1C1D1 DOF/141218 REG/XXXXXEET/EISN0114 EGGX0132 LPPO0239 KZWY0526 TTZP083046N015W0208 45N020W0239 37N030W0410 33N040W0526SEL/TEST ORGN/KHOUUVAX PER/CE/1128 P/TBN R/UVE D/2 10 YELLOW A/RED WHITE BLUE C/TBN)".Replace("(", "").Replace(")","");

 var spltArray = spltLargString.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```